# How to write data into a specific location Firebase Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write data into a specific location in the database. Let's say, I have a couple of users in the database. Each of them has their own personal information, including their e-mails. I want to find the user based on the e-mail, that's to say by using his e-mail (but I don't know exactly whose e-mail it is, but whoever it is do something with that user's information). To be more visible, here is my database sample.

[image]

Now, while working on one of my javascript files, when the user let's say name1 changes his name, I update my object in javascript and want to replace the whole object under ID "-LEp2F2fSDUt94SRU0cx". To cut short, I want to write this updated object in the path ("Users/-LEp2F2fSDUt94SRU0cx") without doing it by hand and just "knowing" the e-mail. So the logic is "Go find the user with the e-mail "name1@yahoo.com" and replace the whole object with his new updated object".  I tried to use orderByChild("Email").equalTo("name1@yahoo.com").set(updated_object), but this syntax does not work I guess. Hopefully I could explain myself.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is the query, that is separate from the post to update. This part is the query to get the value:

```
ref.child('users').orderByChild("Email").equalTo("name1@yahoo.com")
```

To update, you need to do something like this once you have the user id from the query result:

```
ref.child('users').child(userId).child("Email").update(newValue);
```

Comment: ref.child('users').orderByChild("Email").equalTo("name1@yahoo.com") with this line or query we  find the user we need, but after finding the desired user I want to change all his information, I want to use the method "set" to overwrite the existing object. I did not understand what you meant by saying "once you have the user id from the query". I don't need any user id, I need to find the user I want, which we successfully do by the first statement you and I wrote, and the only thing left to do is to set "new_object" (which is an object) into that user's info overwriting the existing one

Comment: @Suren - The object the first query returns should have a $id property. Your set call should use the $id to identify the object you are updating, like I did above. userId = snapshot.key

Answer (score 0):

> #### [firebase.database.Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)
>
> A Query sorts and filters the data at a Database location so only a
> subset of the child data is included. This can be used to order a
> collection of data by some attribute (for example, height of
> dinosaurs) as well as to restrict a large list of items (for example,
> chat messages) down to a number suitable for synchronizing to the
> client. Queries are created by chaining together one or more of the
> filter methods defined here.
>
> ```
> // Find all dinosaurs whose height is exactly 25 meters.
> var ref = firebase.database().ref("dinosaurs");
> ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(25).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
>   console.log(snapshot.key);
> });
> ```